# Understanding Akka FSM `onTransition`

Tags: scala, akka

Im trying to implement Akka FSM in Java and so in the process trying to understand some of the examples written in Scala. I have also looked at the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/fsm.html#overview)

I don't quite understand the purpose of `_` in the case below.

```
onTransition {
    case Uninitialized -> _ => unstashAll()
}
```

Does it to refer to "any" state in the transition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->` thingie is an extractor object defined in [FSM companion object](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/FSM$$$minus$greater$.html). It could be defined as follows:

```
object -> {
   def unapply[A, B](x: (A, B)): Option[(A, B)] = Some(x)
}
```

and it would just match pairs of objects. If one of the sub-patterns is an underscore, then it simply matches every possible object. For example, with the above definition:

```
List((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)).collect{ case x @ (1 -> _) => x }
```

returns

```
List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,3))
```

(all state transitions from `1` to anything), whereas

```
List((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)).collect{ case x @ (_ -> 3) => x }
```

returns

```
List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,3), (2,3))
```

(all state transitions from anything to `3`). It's the same for FSM states.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/java/fsm.html#internal-monitoring) in the end.

In Java this can be written as,

```
onTransition {
    matchState(UNINITIALIZED, null, () -> unstashAll())
}
```